# Limit of the solution of an ODE without obtaining explicitly its solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am dealing with the following IVP:
$$y'=y^2+y-2; \, \, \, y(0)=0$$
I have already proved with Picard-Lindelöf Theorem that it admits an unique solution defined in all $\mathbb{R}$. However, I am asked to prove that the limits of the solution in $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ do exist and calculate them. But I don't know a way of doing it without solving the ODE. Any idea? Thanks for your time.

Comment: there are two constant solutions, $y= 1$   and $y = -2.$  Behavior for a solution lying between these is automatic, it approaches one limit at $- \infty$  and the other at $\infty$ Not a coincidence, solutions outside the constants blow up in finite time, either time forward or time backward. Anyway, draw some pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the two constant solutions $y \in \{1, -2\}$ sometimes it might be efficient to obtain the solution, or a partial solution, before more analysis can be made. In this view make the substitution
$$ y = - \frac{f^{'}}{f} $$
to obtain the second order equation
$$ f^{''} - f^{'} - 2 \, f = 0 $$
which has the solution $f(x) = c_{0} \, e^{-x} + c_{1} \, e^{2 x}$. This leads to
$$ y(x) = \frac{c_{0} \, e^{-x} - 2 \, c_{1} \, e^{2 x}}{c_{0} \, e^{-x} + c_{1} \, e^{2 x}}. $$
Applying the condition $y(0) = 0$ gives
$$ y(x) = \frac{2 \, \left(e^{-x} - e^{2 x}\right)}{2 \, e^{-x} + e^{2 x}}. $$

By changing the functions $y(x)$ takes the forms
\begin{align}
y(x) &= \frac{2 \, \left(e^{- 3 x} - 1\right)}{2 \, e^{- 3 x} + 1}  \to -2 \hspace{5mm} \text{as} \, x \to \infty \\
y(x) &= \frac{2 \, \left(1 - e^{3 x}\right)}{2 + e^{3 x}} \to 1 \hspace{5mm} \text{as} \, x \to -\infty
\end{align}
which shows that the constant terms are limits of the solution.